# How do i resolve Errors in Google Bigquery while creating a table from google sheets?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to create a table in google bigquery from a google sheet. But it keeps throwing up a blank error.

[screen shot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qxR2.png)

I am creating the table from drive.
My format is set to CSV.
I have Schema and input parameters checked.

Comment: Please share some further information so that other users will be able to understand your problem and possibly help you out. Share some code as well as the error that you get.

Comment: thanks @MrfksIV, i've added a screenshot of the error

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the screenshot uploaded and I notice that the URI you put in the  create table window is weird, according to [bigquery/external-data-drive](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-drive) the URI should look like this: `https://drive.google.com/open?id=[FILE_ID]`. I suggest you to get the shareable link instead to only copy the browser link.